# integrate sonarqube with kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, azure-devops, azure, dockerhub, sonarqube

I am trying to integrate sonarqube on kubernetes , my sonarqube service is up and running in when i do "kubectl get services". but i am unable to fetch that url i.e. (Poratal access url).
For deployment purpose i used sonar image which is present inside docker hub [https://hub.docker.com/_/sonarqube[![enter](https://hub.docker.com/_/sonarqube%5B!%5Benter) image description here][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f4S8V.png)][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f4S8V.png)

Comment: What's the question? Your screenshot looks fine to me. Please include your output at text instead of images in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you created your `sonarqube` Service in the `default`namespace, and using SonarQube default ports, your portal URL would be `http://sonarqube.default.svc:9000`.